Solving PDE by Lagrange Method
How do I integrate this ODE?
$$\frac{x y (y \, dx - x \, dy)}{y^2 - x^2} = u \, du$$
This a step at which I am stuck from a longer PDE problem which I am trying to solve using the Lagrange method.
Given the one-parameter family of surfaces defined by $u = cxy (x^2 + y^2)$, where $c$ is a non-zero parameter, we seek a surface that is orthogonal to this family and passes through the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = a^2$, $u = b$ (with $a, b > 0$).

$$\frac{y^2 xdx - x^2 y dy}{y^2 - x^2} = u \, du \tag 1$$
Change of variables :
$$\begin{cases}
X=x^2\\
Y=y^2\\
U=u^2
\end{cases} \quad\implies\quad \frac{YdX - XdY}{Y - X} = dU$$
$$dU=\frac{\partial U}{\partial X}dX+\frac{\partial U}{\partial Y}dY
\quad\implies\quad 
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial U}{\partial X}=\frac{Y}{Y - X}\\
\frac{\partial U}{\partial Y}=\frac{- X}{Y - X}
\end{cases}
$$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial X\partial Y}=\frac{1}{Y - X}-\frac{Y}{(Y - X)^2}=-\frac{X}{(Y - X)^2}\\
\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial Y\partial X}=\frac{- 1}{Y - X}-\frac{X}{(Y - X)^2}=-\frac{Y}{(Y - X)^2}
\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial X\partial Y}\neq\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial Y\partial X}\quad\implies\quad\text{no solution,}$$
except on $Y=X$ and $y=\pm x$ , indetermined eq.$(1)$ for $u$.
